# How can I join table to the variable in Jmeter for testing database

Tags: sql, database, jmeter

I have I have two different server connections (2 JDBC Connection Configuration)

1. From the first server I get data from the table and in Jmeter create variable 'prod' and store it as a string [image]

In view result tree 'Response data' I have columns and rows as expected[image]

2. In the second server I want to join one table to the data from the first server connection using SQL below:
   [image]
   When I look in 'Response data' of Result tree I have this mistake:
   '**The identifier that starts with '{Locale=es, Position=null,CREATED_BY_Orign=null, CREATED_DATE=2020-02-11 16:30:55.199' is too long. Maximum length is 128.**'

Question: Can I use a variable to join one table to another? OR I need to create a table in the second server and populate it with data from the first server variable? If so, could you please explain how to do it?

P.S. Servers are not linked and can't be

Comment: Hello @Aliaksandra, I think you will find the solution here at [multiple-databases-and-servers][1], it is a nice article to read. 
[1]: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-test-multiple-databases-and-servers-on-jmeter

Comment: Thank you for the article, I read it. There they use JOIN , but I want to use LEFT JOIN, maybe you know how to apply it in JMETER according to the article steps?

Comment: if you want to use left or right join, it is so simple, the idea here you have a table, i.e **tbl_user with: uid, uName** and **tbl_info with: idinfo, uid, info**
now, we want uid, uName, and info which is in other table:

select tbl_user.uid, tbl_user.uName, tbl_info.info from tbl_user left join tbl_info on (tbl_user.uid = tbl_info.uid)

so just to recap that, we placed tbl_user from **LEFT** side and then **tbl_info**also used **left join** with that, if it is not clear in the comment I will place that in the answer.
**use DB names like db1.tbl_user, db2.tbl_info**
You are welcome.

Comment: @AwatITWork Could you place it  in the answer, please, and write a bit more. Thank you. With example. I barely understand in words

Comment: @AwatITWork I was talking about the article you sent. In Jmeter I do not how to write correctly because another table from another server. SQL syntax I know but in Jmeter I do not know how to correctly work with variables using LEFT JOIN

Comment: give me a moment I will download and implement that for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243115/discussion-between-aliaksandra-and-awatitwork).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late, since I don't use that it took some time to do configuration done,
Anyways let me descript what I am doing here, and how it can be done, starting from configuration I have 2 databases in my localhost, **test**, and **stack**
I have created your scenario in which **tbl_Student sid, sName** has some info from another database test, **tbl_info with idinfo, uid, info**, now I want to get info for each student.

I am using **left join**, here I am telling MySQL to give me all records from tbl_Student but I don't care if we have null in tbl_info

```
select 
stcak.tbl_student.sid, stcak.tbl_student.sName,test.tbl_info.info 
from 
stcak.tbl_student left join test.tbl_info 
on (stcak.tbl_student.sid = test.tbl_info.uid)
```

If you see in my query I have provided DB name also, Test and Stack

```
<dbname>.<tablename>.<colName>
stcak.tbl_student.sid
```

Just to tell you what is going on, all game-changer is from the configuration and specifically the username, as you know I am connecting with **root** which has the privileges for all databases, in my case Test and Stack, but if the database in different serves I saw something like **HandleRequestSet** which can be used to combine the response with other respons I think.

I have also provided some images, you can check from your end.
[image: Config]
[image: Query]
[image: Result]
[image: Result Set]

Comment: If you had 2 servers, you would create 2 JDBC connections and nothing changed according to your approach? In the first connection you would write 'use stack' and in the second connection 'use test' ? I can't find any info on HandleRequestSet could you please share a useful link or screenshots

Comment: I do not quite understand why your case is similar to my. You have in one server 2 databases but I have 2 servers. In your server there are both databases so we can reach them <dbname>.<tablename>.<colName>  as you mentioned  but my databases are not in one server

Comment: @Aliaksandra, I have only this one, but I will try to set up another server and combine the result for you, but I am sure there are so many ways to implement this, if the data you are dealing with is not so big, you can **fetch** the data from one server into another table, so both data will be in one server. but I am pretty sure there are so many ways to artchive this.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is big so the table creation will be not effective as supposed. I fully understand the article you sent but my case seems to be different. I will be glad, if you show how to deal with two servers and  apply LEFT JOIN one table server to another.

Comment: I do not what to change in your approach so that it will work for me

Comment: I will do that for you, give me a moment since I don't use JMeter, but I am pretty sure it has some features like that, you are most welcome @Aliaksandra, I will do that for ya.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot provide a comprehensive answer because we don't know what you're going to do with this data next.

On JMeter level the result object is stored as [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of [Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) so you can implement the "join" using Groovy scripting.

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for more information.